# Swift UILocalNotification Title

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm using following code to display my notification:

```
var takePillAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    takePillAction.identifier = "pillTakenAction"
    takePillAction.title = "Pille eingenommen"
    takePillAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.background
    takePillAction.isDestructive = false
    takePillAction.isAuthenticationRequired = false
```

If I test it on a 3D touch device the notification is shown correctly with the button title. But if I test it on a device without 3D touch the notification is shown, but if I swipe the notification to the left, the button title is View. If I touch this the notification is shown bigger with the correct button.
Is there a way to override the view title to my title and use this button to perform my action?